# UISegmentedControl not changing the value fetched from fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am doing a project in which I have to fetch data from two separate URLs. The URLs contain json for weather for two different places. I am using a UISegmentedControl to switch between the two places and display the data in the UITableView. I am using Core Data, so the json is fetched and the data is stored in the coredata and then I use the fetchedResultsController.

My problem is that when I change from segment1 which shows the weather data from the first city to segment2 which should show the data for the second city. It does nothing and shows just the data that is fetched from the first URL.

Here is the snippet of the code -

This is my IBAction for segmented control

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    //for Sydney Weather
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [self refreshDataWithURL:sydneyWeatherURL atLocation:@"Sydney"];
        NSLog(@"SYDNEY");
    }
    //for Mosman weather
    else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [self refreshDataWithURL:mosmanWeatherURL atLocation:@"Mosman"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"MOSMAN");
    }
}
```

This is the refreshDataWithURL method used in the above code -

```
- (void)refreshDataWithURL:(NSString *)stringURL atLocation:(NSString *)location {

    self.managedObjectContext = [CoreDataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *weatherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    GetWeatherData *getWeatherData = [[GetWeatherData alloc] initWithURL:weatherURL andContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    NSLog(@"Fetching Data for %@", location);
    [getWeatherData getWeather];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And this is my fetchedResultsController -

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription  = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DailyForecast" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

[fetchRequest setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES];
//Get the latest weather data
NSDate *currentdate = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@)", currentdate];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

//order the result from newest to oldest
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];

NSLog(@"FETCH REQUEST --- %@", fetchRequest);

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"date" cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
[[[self fetchedResultsController] managedObjectContext] performBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [theFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, Error Description: %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort(); //Fail
    } else {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }];
    }
}];

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

There are other frc delegate methods as well. I read in other topics that there should be two managedObjectContexts that should handle both the URLs, but I have no clue how to do that.

This is the GetWeatherData .m file -

```
- (void)getWeather {
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_yahooApiURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
NSURLResponse *urlResponse;

NSError *error;
//Fetch data from the URL

NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

UIAlertView *alertView;
if (urlData != nil) {
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [[[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"channel"] objectForKey:@"item"] objectForKey:@"forecast"];

    NSString *location = [[[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"channel"] objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"city"];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonArray) {
        [DailyForecast getForecastWithWeatherAPI:dictionary forLocation:location inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    }

} else {
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There is an error in connecting to the internet" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertView show];
}
```

}

Can anybody please help, your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code for the `GetWeatherData` class.

Comment: @pbasdf I have added the GetWeatherData.m code. The _yahooURL mentioned is in another method of the GetWeatherData file which is fetching the URL from ACCTableViewController.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually hoping to see the code where you insert into CoreData, but I guess that's in `DailyForecast`.  I am asking because your fetched results controller fetches ALL (future) forecasts, but it isn't limited to just the location you are interested in.  Do you store the location as an attribute of `DailyForecast` entity?  If so, just add the location to the FRC predicate.

Comment: @pbasdf there are two urls for two different cities - city1 and city2. initially when i am on segment1 (uisegmentedcontrol) it fetches the data from city1 url. when i tap on segment2 it calls the refreshdata function which i have mentioned above which fetches data from city2 url. it fetches all the data but is not displaying it in the tableview.

Comment: Unless you delete it, the data from the previous location will still be stored in CoreData.

Comment: how do i delete the data? I tried calling the reset method in the IBAction where I change the uisegment, so before i do the refreshdatawithurl in segment2 i call '[_managedObjectContext reset]'. Is there any other way?

Comment: If you have saved the context, then everything will have been written to the store, and will survive a reset of the context.  If you have not saved the context, then the reset should remove everything (and your problem is not what I thought).  If you have saved the context, then to delete the existing data you have to fetch all the objects and delete them one by one.